# Cannot understand how the gdb memory dump of my struct with bitfields is correct given my struct initialisation

Tags: c, serialization, struct, endianness, bit-fields

I have designed a Packet struct for a custom networking protocol as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t src;
    uint8_t dest;
    uint8_t len;
    uint8_t flag;

    //bitfields allocated R-L? gcc is somehow merging the fields also?
    uint8_t type :4;
    uint16_t seq :12; // 12 bits used for this field.[F3|02] == 0x02F3 on litle endian?
    
    uint8_t checksum;
}Packet;
```

From my understanding of bitfields and struct padding, each field would be stored in contiguous bytes (seq will start at a new byte boundary). No trailing padding either since my device is x64 as well.

Graphically: `|src|dest|len|flag|type|  seq  |checksum|` 64 bit header, no struct padding.

To test my packet for further serialisation, I initialised a packet via:

```
    thispack.src = 0x07;
    thispack.dest = 0x34;
    thispack.len = 0x5F;
    thispack.flag = 0xA2;
    thispack.type = 0x05;
    thispack.seq = 0xAED;
    thispack.checksum= 0x23;
```

I am running on a little endian system. I expect the memory layout of the struct to be:

`0x07   0x34   0x5F   0xA2   0x05   0xED   0x0A   0x23`, with the bytes of seq reversed by little-endian rules.

However, running `x/8bx &thispack` in gdb returns the following:

`0x07    0x34    0x5f    0xa2    0xd5    0xae    0x23    0x00`

I cannot understand how 0xD5 and 0xAE are obtained. This leads to uncertainty while accessing struct fields via `.` notation:

Here's what I feel is correct:

1. `uint8_t mytype = thispack.type` should store `0x05` in the byte referred to by `mytype`.
2. `uint16_t myseq = thispack.seq` should store `0xED 0x0A` in the 2 bytes allocated to myseq.

I cannot see how it could be anything else.

Comment: I read that a bitfield must start at a new byte boundary if it cannot fit completely in the spare space of the previous data-type. (12 bit seq will not fit into the remaining 4 bits of uint8_t type)

From what I understand, I think  __attribute__(packed) would lead to the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: Re “I read that a bitfield must start at a new byte boundary if it cannot fit completely in the spare space of the previous data-type.” There is no such rule in the C standard. C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 says “… If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined…”

Comment: There is an equivalent description in the beginning of the post (with an accompanying graph)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054590/how-to-visualize-the-layout-of-a-c-struct-with-bitfields-in-memory is where I read about insufficient space. (in the answer by supercat)

Also, what exactly does "implementation-defined" mean here? I am new to C and i've seen the term a lot.

Comment: The text I quoted is verbatim from the C standard. The C standard is authoritative on the C standard. The question you link to is not.

Comment: Alright.  In that case, does gcc on my device pack bitfields? (Given my memory outputs from gdb).
Could there be a different reason for the memory to not be laid out in the order I expected?

Comment: Because bit fields can be done in any order that a given C compiler chooses [based on CPU architecture, packing, endianness, etc.], this is _not_ portable across platforms. So, I would _not_ put them into a `struct` that is part of a _network_ protocol. Consider using `htons`, `htonl`, etc. Then, do the bit fields by writing your own macros that use and/or/shift. Or, just use bytes, shorts, etc. and avoid bit fields [in any form] altogether (e.g. `uint8_t type; uint16_t seq;`) The bits you save with the bit fields isn't worth the complexity. You may want: `__attribute__((packed))` as well.

Comment: I agree, removing bitfields altogether would work here. 
That said, I still can't see how exaclty gcc is reordering my packet fields in memory (which fields are combined etc.). Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

> Alright. In that case, does gcc on my device pack bitfields?

Yes:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t type :4;
    uint16_t seq :12; // 12 bits used for this field.[F3|02] == 0x02F3 on litle endian?
}Packet;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(Packet));
}
```

The result https://godbolt.org/z/1Teh7Er9f:

```
2
```

> Could there be a different reason for the memory to not be laid out in
> the order I expected?

No, You need to use a small workaround:

```
typedef struct {
    struct {uint8_t type :4;};
    struct {uint16_t seq :12;}; // 12 bits used for this field.[F3|02] == 0x02F3 on litle endian?
}__attribute__((packed)) Packet;

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(Packet));
}
```

The result https://godbolt.org/z/1MGPYsW1W:

```
3
```